# How to get PHP DOM getElementsByTagName('body') with html tags

Tags: php, html, dom

Im getting the body content but without html tags(It is cleaned up) inside the body.**I need with all html tags inside the body.** what do I want to change on my code?

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($myURL);

$elements2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');

        foreach ($elements2 as $el2) {
            echo $el2->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
        echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: You output HTML and this is interpreted by your browser. Either use `htmlentities()` or set the MIME type (`header('Content-Type: text/plain')`) or look at the raw source code in your browser.

Comment: @ComFeek you telling like this     **echo htmlentities($el2->nodeValue, PHP_EOL);** , it is not working, it is throwing an error

Comment: @Wazan No, you used it incorrectly, try this: `htmlentities($el2->nodeValue, ENT_HTML5), PHP_EOL;`

Comment: When I use like this generating unwanted keywords like &NewLine;&comma; . but not getting these tags **h,p,br,div**. I want to generate all.

Comment: Surprised that you are getting the (text) content at all – because according to DOM specification the `nodeValue` for DOM nodes of type `ELEMENT_NODE` (which `body` is) should be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to save the `body` child nodes as HTML. I suggest using Xpath to fetch the nodes, this avoids the outer loop:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
  <body>
    Foo
    <p>Bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$result = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//body/node()') as $node) {
  $result .= $document->saveHtml($node);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
string(29) "
    Foo
    <p>Bar</p>
  "
```